# How to show that $\mathbb{1}:(X*Y)*Z\to X*(Y*Z)$ needn't be homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Given two spaces $X$ and $Y$, the join $X*Y$ is the quotient space of $X\times Y\times I$ under the identifications $(x,y_1,0)\sim (x,y_2,0)$ and $(x_1,y,1)\sim (x_2,y,1)$. Thus we are collapsing the subspace $X\times Y\times\{0\}$ to $X$ and $X\times Y\times\{1\}$ to $Y$.

A nice way to write points of $X*Y$ is as formal linear combinations $t_1x + t_2y$
with $0\leq t_i\leq 1$ and $t_1+t_2=1$, subject to the rules $0x + 1y = y$ and $1x + 0y = x$
that correspond exactly to the identifications defining $X*Y$ . In much the same
way, an iterated join $X_1*\cdots *X_n$ can be constructed as the space of formal linear
combinations $t_1x_1+\cdots+ t_nx_n$ with $0\leq t_i\leq 1$ and $t_1+\cdots+t_n=1$, with the
convention that terms $0x_i$ can be omitted.

Please give an example to show that $\mathbb{1}:(X*Y)*Z\to X*(Y*Z)$ defined by $t_1x + t_2y+t_3z\mapsto t_1x + t_2y+t_3z$ needn't be homeomorphic.

Comment: [Relevant MO question.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110922/associativity-of-topological-join-and-join-of-spheres)